# How are sinusoids and roots of unity related to each other?

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing, roots-of-unity

The discrete Fourier transform (DFT) is often teached as being a transform that decomposes a given signal or sequence of numbers into sinusoids with frequencies $\large\frac{k}{N}$ where $k \in [0, N-1]$ and $N$ is the signal length (number of numbers in the sequence).

For $\mathbf{x} = (x_{0}, ..., x_{N-1})$ the DFT is defined as

$$ X_{k} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_{n}\omega^{kn}_{N} \quad 0 \leq k \leq N-1$$

where $\omega_{N} = e^{\large\frac{-2\pi i}{N}}$ is a primitive $N$th root of unity. So, what I want to ask is

> What exactly is the connection between sinusoids and (primitive) roots of unity?

I don't see a root of unity being simply a sinusoidal wave. In that case it would be defined as $$y(t) = A\sin(2\pi ft + \theta)$$ as is usual ...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not being a mathematician it is really difficult for me to see. I learned the DFT while studying signal processing (from an applied perspective). Now later on I am trying to figure out the math..

Comment: The Discrete Fourier Transform comes from numerically integrating the Fourier coefficients, which for a function $f \in C_{2\pi}$ (continous, $2\pi$-periodic), are given by

$ c_k(f) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(u) e^{-iku} du. $

If you decompose this with equidistant nodes $\frac{2 \pi j}{N}$, $j= 0, \dots, N$ and use the trapezoidal rule you get

$c_k(f) \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} f(\frac{2 \pi j}{N})e^{-2 \pi i j k / N}.$

Now, with $\omega_N := e^{-2 \pi i / N}$ you get the DFT.

The $e^{ikx}$ come from an orthogonal system and are sinusoid.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. So roots of unity are kind of sampled sinusoids?

Answer (score 1):

The $N^{th}$ root of unity is a complex number of the form $e^{j2\pi/N}$. A sinusoidal wave is a function like so:

$$
e^{j\omega t} = \cos(\omega t) + j \sin(\omega t),
$$

where $j=\sqrt{-1}$. The formula you are looking at uses the roots of unity for convenience/preference/cleanliness, though I don't like it and find it confusing. When you raise a root of unity to $kn$ as is done in the sum, you get

$$
w_N^{kn} = (e^{j2\pi/N})^{kn} = e^{j2\pi kn/N} = \cos(2\pi kn/N) + j \sin(2\pi kn/N),
$$

so each $w_N^{nk}$ in the sum is a sinusoidal wave of a different frequency.